# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I am facing this error when i create an account & contact by calling another test class:

Apex Class:(My code starts with else block)

```
public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) {
       .....

        if (....) {
            .......
        }
        **else{
           Account accountToInactive = (Account)so;


     Map<Id,Account> accountList=new Map<Id,Account>([Select id,Inactive__c from Account where Id=:accountToInactive.Id]);
       Map<Id,Contact> cont= new Map<Id,Contact>([Select Id,Name,Inactive__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =:accountToInactive.Id AND Inactive__c=:false]);

        if(accountList.size()>0){

      for(ID idkey:accountList.keySet())
       {
        Account acc = accountList.get(idkey);
        if(acc.Inactive__c== true){
            //if(acc.Contacts.size() > 0)
            if(cont.size()>0)
            {
                so.addError(Label.Active_Contact_Error);

            }

            else{}        
       }
       else{} 
       }
    }
 else{}

        }
    }**
```

Test Class:

```
 **@isTest static void testInactiveAccount(){


    Account acct = TestData.createAccount('TestAcc','Customer' ,false);
     insert acct;


     Contact cnt=TestData.createContact('Test','Contact','test@test.com',acct.Id,true);
           cnt.Inactive__c=false;
           insert cnt;


    }

}**
```

in the test class 'TestData' is the another class where by passing the parameter, account and contact is getting created.but I am facing an error that I mentioned in the heading.
Can someone help me what is wrong in the test class..

Comment: answer is pretty easy. Your TestData class already inserts an account or contact. SO, in your test method you need to update it. You can not insert record twice in salesforce

Comment: @kurunve Thanks..One thing I want to ask in my test class there are 3 test methods where via FOR loop account is created in one test method account is created 200 times so techically 200 times SOQL query is firing for creating an account.I am facing below error:                                        Too many SOQL queries: 101   Can you tell me how can i bypass or avoid this error....

Comment: create method for bulk creation of records -- as parameters apply count of records, and list of corresponding parameters. create account in loop, and add them to list. do DML on list. If you need to query anything -- query it before loop

Comment: ah, issue is in trigger as well. pattern that you currently use is not really great for bulkification on record level. you dont need to query all the accounts it trigger as well as you already have them, and you need to query contacts for all the account ids via one request

Comment: But the difficulty is In my test class there are no of test methods created already adn in this case I have to create a seperate method inwhich i have to create account and it related contacts.If i modify it to the existing test class methods that would impact other functionality.In my case,Apex class is itself a trigger inwhich they specified all the methods of trigger.and in Trigger we simply call our apex class.Entire logic is included in Apex class.

Comment: @kurunve But the difficulty is In my test class there are no of test methods created already adn in this case I have to create a seperate method inwhich i have to create account and it related contacts.If i modify it to the existing test class methods that would impact other functionality.In my case,Apex class is itself a trigger inwhich they specified all the methods of trigger.and in Trigger we simply call our apex class.Entire logic is included in Apex class.

Comment: so, you have 2 ways -- write that method for bulk creation. As well as you can write test method and call inside not dml, but only single beforeUpdate method, as mentioned in you comment. But in perfect world, it would be always nice to have 2 ways -- test method itself as well as test entire DML process,  also with bulk test data